# Why do these two way to compare Class objects result differently?

Tags: java, java.lang.class

I've defined two classes : Employee and Doctor, They're father and son. The code like this:

```java
class Employee {
  // ....
}

class Doctor extends Employee {
  // ....
}
```

And then I wrote a main method like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        System.out.println(doctor.getClass() == new Employee().getClass());  // code 1
        System.out.println(employee.getClass() == Employee.class);  // code 2
        System.out.println(doctor.getClass() == Employee.class); // code 3
    }
```

but only `code 1` and `code 2`  is correct and `code 3` calls exception :

```
Error:(33, 46) Java: uncomparable type: java.lang.Class<capture#1 extends Doctor> and java.lang.Class<Employee>
```

and I know I can use `equals` to deal with this problem, but I want to know why I can't use operator `==` to compare them.

Comment: Maybe try `.equals`?

Comment: `Class` objects are unique per class as long as you use the same class-loader, so it's usually correct to compare them by `==`. The error in this case is because the comparison can never be true, and the compiler is telling you so because you would probably not want to check a condition that could never be a true.

Comment: the `doctor` variable cannot hold an instance of just `Person` (or `Employee`) - it must be an instance of `Doctor` or any subclass of that - so that comparison is useless and the compiler is trying to *help* avoid such (it is a compile error, not an `Exception` {unless running code that didn't compile correctly})

Comment: No problem; I've edited to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you observe is correct, but to explain why, we need to refer to the Java Language Specification.

[§15.8.2. Class Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) says

> The type of `C.class`, where `C` is the name of a class, interface, or array type (§4.3), is `Class<C>`.

[§4.3.2. The Class `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2) says:

> The type of a method invocation expression of `getClass` is `Class<? extends |T|>`, where `T` is the class or interface that was searched for `getClass` (§15.12.1) and `|T|` denotes the erasure of `T` (§4.6).

[§15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators `==` and `!=`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) says:

> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal (ignoring the case where both values are `null`).

So, we can write down the compile-time types of each expression:

- `Employee.class` is of type `Class<Employee>`.
- `Doctor.class` is of type `Class<Doctor>`.
- `employee.getClass()` and `new Employee().getClass()` are both of type `Class<? extends Employee>`. This means a `Class` representing either `Employee` or a subclass of it, including `Doctor`.
- `doctor.getClass()` and `new Doctor().getClass()` are both of type `Class<? extends Doctor>`. This means a `Class` representing either `Doctor` or a subclass of it, e.g. `Surgeon` perhaps.

Now we can explain all three behaviours:

1. `doctor.getClass() == new Employee().getClass()` compares a `Class<? extends Doctor>` with `Class<? extends Employee>`. The first type can be converted to the second type by a casting conversion, so this is allowed.
2. `employee.getClass() == Employee.class` compares a `Class<? extends Employee>` with a `Class<Employee>`. The second type can be converted to the first type by a casting conversion, so this is allowed.
3. `doctor.getClass() == Employee.class` compares a `Class<? extends Doctor>` with a `Class<Employee>`. Neither type can be converted to the other by a casting conversion, so this is a compile-time error (not an exception).

Going into bit more detail on 3., a `Class<? extends Doctor>` could be satisfied by `Class<Doctor>` or `Class<Surgeon>`, but not by `Class<Employee>` because `Employee` is not a subtype of `Doctor`. However, you could write a similar expression which has the intended result if you upcast `doctor` before calling `getClass`:

4. `((Employee) doctor).getClass() == Employee.class` is similar to case 2., so it is allowed.

It is admittedly quite unusual to fix a type error by upcasting instead of downcasting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, I have understood the reason !!